# ios9 app transport security issues different in simulator and device

Tags: ios, ios9, app-transport-security

upon running my app in ios9 simulator, i get app transport security related issues because some of my urls are not using https. I tried it in an ipad with ios9 and its working fine.

Upon release of ios9, should I expect my live app (sdk 8) to fail on ios9 devices? Just making sure if late appstore updates are safe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html)

> If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS **as much as you can** right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as soon as possible. In addition, your communication through higher-level APIs needs to be encrypted using TLS version 1.2 with forward secrecy. If you try to make a connection that doesn't follow this requirement, an error is thrown. If your app needs to make a request to an insecure domain, you have to specify this domain in your app's Info.plist file.

Comment: Hi Arsen, I have an app that has ATS enabled, web server supports TLS 1.2, however the Cert on that web server is not supporting FS yet, the app works fine in simulator but doesn't work on devices. Could you please take a look out my issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43286204/an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-server-cannot-be-made

Answer (score 1):

I have written a summary and ways to how to check Acceptability of Webservice for iOS 9's App transport security

https://medium.com/@Mrugraj/app-transport-security-b7910c4fc70f

It have two ways

1. Using Curl

   $ curl -v https://github.com/
   Trying 192.30.252.130...
2. Using online tool like - https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html