# “an ssl error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made” connecting to Internal Development Server on phone only

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I developed a iOS app that connects to a internal web server. When I used the simulator, it works fine, but when I build the same app on a iPhone, it gives me a error message “an ssl error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. " Why the error only occurs on iPhone not in simulator?

Here is my environment
Xcode 8.2
iOS 10.3
Objective C -- My client code is using ATS by default
AFNetworking Framework 3.1
Web Server -- Support TLS 1.2 only
Web Server Cert is not supporting forward secrecy yet.

Could it be because that my Cert is not ATS compliant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After I read this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) from Apple

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Your Domain</key>   
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

My app is now working on devices. My cert on the server is not Forward Secrecy ready yet.

Comment: Also should be noted that Apple will not require justification for this ATS exception because the forward secrecy exception is not one requiring explicit justification by Apple.  That said, if you can remove that exception before submitting to Apple, that would be ideal.

Comment: Thank you @wottle, my server is windows 2008 R2, to have a Cert that supports ECDSA with ECDHE key, the OS has to be Windows 2012 R2, I'm waiting for the server team to upgrade our server.

Comment: Another thing is this app is an enterprise app, so I don't need to submit it to Apple store.

Comment: That's good.  It's still best practice to enable as few ATS exceptions as possible.  It doesn't guarantee you are secure, but it can keep future developers from doing things that may unintentionally expose data when on untrusted networks.

Comment: It turns out that I can't fully implement the ATS yet, the Cert that needs to support forward secrecy also needs to put on the firewall server, we are using F5 firewall server, it is not compatible yet.